# Как сделать такое на js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как сделать, есть выдвижное меню, оно закрывается если кликнуть вне меню на фон, собственно как сделать что бы оно также закрывалось если нажать на саму ссылку в меню, нажал на ссылку и оно также сразу скрылось, мб кто разбирается в js и скажет, заранее спасибо

Меню:

```
<nav>
<div class="drawer">
<div class="nav-head">
<div class="head-cont">
<img class="avatar" src="/img/avatar.png">
<div class="tit">
<span class="name"><b>XAOTIK</b></span>
Material Design
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="nav-cont">
<a class="nav-link" href="/"><span class="material-icons">home</span> Главная</a>
<a class="nav-link" href=""><span class="material-icons">person</span> Профиль</a>
<a class="nav-link" href=""><span class="material-icons">rss_feed</span> Новости</a>
<a class="nav-link" href=""><span class="material-icons">notifications</span> Уведомления</a>
<a class="nav-link" href=""><span class="material-icons">chat_bubble</span> Сообщения</a>
<a class="nav-link" href=""><span class="material-icons">group</span> Друзья</a>
<a class="nav-link" href=""><span class="material-icons">logout</span> Выход</a>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

JS

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
 
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
            function cl(el) {
                return document.getElementsByClassName(el);
            }
            function Drawer() {
                var drawers = cl('drawer');
                var drawers_cover = cl('drawer_cover');
                if (drawers.length > 0) {
                    var drawerCover = document.createElement("div");
                    drawerCover.className = 'drawer_cover';
                    document.body.appendChild(drawerCover);
 
                    cl('nav_main')[0].onclick = function() {
                        drawers[0].classList.toggle('drawer_in');
                        drawers_cover[0].classList.toggle('drawer_op');
                    };
 
                    cl('drawer_cover')[0].onclick = function() {
                        drawers[0].classList.toggle('drawer_in');
                        drawers_cover[0].classList.toggle('drawer_op');
                    };
 
                }
            }
            Drawer();
 
            jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
                var d = e(".hide"),
                s = e(".cd-secondary-nav"),
                a = e(".sub-nav-hero"),
                i = (d.height(), !1),
                n = 0,
                o = 10,
                l = 150;
                function r() {
                    var r, t, h, v = e(window).scrollTop();
                    a.length > 0 ? (
                        t = v,
                        h = a.offset().top - s.height() - d.height(),
                        n >= t ? t < h ? (
                            d.removeClass("hidden"),
                            s.removeClass("fixed slide-up"),
                            a.removeClass("secondary-nav-fixed")
                            ): n - t > o && (
                            d.removeClass("is-hidden"),
                            s.removeClass("slide-up").addClass("fixed"),
                            a.addClass("secondary-nav-fixed")
                            ): t > h + l ? (
                            d.addClass("hidden"),
                            s.addClass("fixed slide-up"),
                            a.addClass("secondary-nav-fixed")
                            ): t > h && (
                            d.removeClass("hidden"),
                            s.addClass("fixed").removeClass("slide-up"),
                            a.addClass("secondary-nav-fixed")
                            )
                            ): n - (r = v) > o ? d.removeClass("hidden"): r - n > o && r > l && d.addClass("hidden"),
                    n = v,
                    i = !1
                }
                e(window).on("scroll", function() {
                    i || (i = !0,
                        window.requestAnimationFrame ? requestAnimationFrame(r): setTimeout(r, 250))
                }),
                e(window).on("resize", function() {
                    d.height()
                })
            });
```

Comment: Ну наверняка если меню выдвижное, то есть кнопка для раскрытия меню.
Просто привяжите событие клик и метод toogle для (show и hide)
Накидал маленький пример для скрытия и открытия меню:
[https://codepen.io/pen/][1]

Comment: Ваша ссылка не работает(, мне бы этот код дополнить что я дал и в ссылки что то добавить что бы работало только с ними(